# Ionic change language with ion-select-option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I implement a language switch using ion-select-option to pass value and change the language file
here is the html code

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Language </ion-label>
    <ion-select placeholder="Select One" [(ngModel)]="lang" (ionChange)="switchLanguage()" interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-select-option value="ar" selected="true">Arabic</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

and the ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  lang: any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    public translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.lang = 'ar';
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('ar');
    this.translate.use('ar');
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  switchLanguage() {
    this.translate.use(this.lang);
    console.log(this.lang);
  }



}
```

the console always return with "ar"
any idea where is the issue?

Comment: you might want to remove the `selected` attribute of the first `option` tag, since your model is initialized to this very value.

Comment: @Nicolas still the same

Comment: You could create a [mre] to help us understand your problem ?

Comment: @Nicolas I made an edit to the post and attached the full app.component.ts file

Comment: I try to reproduce your problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-epl4hx?file=app/app.component.ts) and i could not. Maybe you could use this as an example and try to fix your problem on your side.

Comment: I don't know what it the problem .. Just changed the ion-option to ion-select-option cause I use ionic 5 and still the same result

Comment: Maybe your problem is not in what you've provided. I think you have a bit of debugging to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replace `this.lang` with an event

ts

```
switchLanguage($event) {
    this.translate.use($event.target.value);
    console.log($event.target.value);
  }
```

html

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Language </ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="Select One" [(ngModel)]="lang" (ionChange)="switchLanguage($event)" interface="action-sheet">
          <ion-select-option value="ar">Arabic</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-select placeholder="Select Language" 
    [(ngModel)]="loginCredentials.language"
    (ngModelChange)="changeLanguage(loginCredentials.language)">
    <ion-select-option value="0">Select Language</ion-select-option> 
    
    <ion-select-option value="ar">Arabic</ion-select-option>
    
                         <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
                     
    
     </ion-select>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    changeLanguage(language) {
    
        this.translate.setDefaultLang(language)
     
        }
```